# In neo4j, filter certain relationships by mutual connects

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get all the intermediate nodes between two nodes such that when given a certain type of relationship, only mutually connected nodes are returned.

Here's some sample data to help me explain my problem: [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=4jhr8g).

I'm looking for the mutual connected nodes between P1 and P3. For relationships like "studies", I'm OK with unidirectional edges. However, for the relationship "connects", I want to be able to filter out the nodes where there isn't a bi-directional edge. Thus, the query should return only S1 and P5.

How do I filter my query so P2 and P4 don't show up(because there is no bi-directional edge between them and either P1 and P3)?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to take into account the number of paths a intermediate node appears. If count equals 1 then it's part of the result

```
MATCH (a:Person { name: 'p1' })-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c:Person { name: 'p3' })
WITH b, count(*) AS count
WHERE count=1
RETURN b
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person { name: 'p1' })-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c:Person { name: 'p3' })
WITH a,c,b,type(r1) AS rel_type1,collect(r1) AS rels1, collect(r2) AS rels2, type(r2) AS rel_type2
WHERE (length(rels1)=1 OR startNode(rels1[0])=endNode(rels1[0])) AND (length(rels2)=1 OR startNode(rels2[0])=endNode(rels2[1]))
RETURN *
```

Results:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rels2             | rel_type1  | a                  | b                  | c                  | rels1             | rel_type2  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [:studies[10] {}] | "studies"  | Node[0]{name:"p1"} | Node[5]{name:"s1"} | Node[2]{name:"p3"} | [:studies[9] {}]  | "studies"  |
| [:connects[8] {}] | "connects" | Node[0]{name:"p1"} | Node[1]{name:"p2"} | Node[2]{name:"p3"} | [:connects[0] {}] | "connects" |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows
35 ms
```

Here is the console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/8m9u78